# Using UI-Router multiple states with different URLs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to develop a UI for my designer but have ran into a bit of a problem trying to get UI-Router and Angular to work correctly in this manner.  On the Home page I have 2 sections, Users and Groups.  The Home page has a URL of `/home` and I want to be able to select a User OR a Group and have the URL change to either `/home/user/:id` or `/home/group/:id` respectively.  The problem is that I want the nested view to appear directly below the corresponding section. So if they select a User, it will open up the User view underneath the Users section and vice versa with Groups.

I thought this could be acheived with multiple views like `<div ui-view="users"></div>` and `<div ui-view="groups"></div>`, but there is no sense of state when using this. The views just render automatically regardless of the URL (state).

Is there a way to achieve this using ui-router by maintaining state whilst utilizing 2 views?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vfz1l4GAdBdhkyC6zMgQ?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but it can get complicated, could you set up a plunker? This way we can work on that sample....

Comment: Please restructure your question to include code examples and an, "As you can see, A is happening, but I want B." statement

Comment: Before I attempt to set up a plunker, is this supported at all or are you saying this requires a hack to get working? If it does, then I would rather just abandon the design and use something else

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think it's built to work that way, it sounds pretty hacky. You typically have one state for one URL. I recommend a different approach.

Comment: nope, not a hack. it's on the documentation. Hard to give the right example without seeing how you structure your states, but take a look: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: yes I have read this documentation, but multiple named views dont have as state.. they are just always rendered on the page. I want different views to render different templates at different URLs

Comment: @TonyBarnes I still want 1 URL for 1 state. I just want my state to render in a different ui-view based on what state is being instantiated

Comment: I have added a plunker that outlines what I am looking for

Comment: I think the cleanest way to do this would be to have a property in `HomeController` which stores a value for the state that you are in, and use `ng-if` to render the `ui-view` if the state matches.

Comment: The easiest way I have been able to make sense of this is with abstract views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract state to create a layout, then reference that state as parent to other states.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2C3pSAgFzuer3gOnF2LW?p=preview)

```
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
abstract: true,
views: {
  '@': {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
  },
  'user@home': {},
  'group@home': {
    templateUrl: 'group.html'
  }
}
}).state('root', {
  parent: 'home',
  url: '/',
  views: { . . }

}).state('home.user', {
  parent: 'home',
  url: '/user',
  views: {
    'user@home': {
      controller: 'UserController',
      templateUrl: 'user.html'
    },
    'group@home': {}
  }

})
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, I will give it a try. Could you explain what the need of the root state is?

Comment: Since the home state is abstract it's not active on it's own.